# how to get global variable value in store to pass as extraparam without controller in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

this is my store.js
i have defined appid in app.js as global variable and assigned value in some page but still it shows globals undefined.please provide answer.

```
Ext.define('Application.store.online.ApplicationDev', {
            extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
            storeId : 'appliaction',
            autoLoad : false,
            pageSize : 18,
            fields : ['total'],
            proxy : {
                type : 'ajax',
                url : 'GetApplicationIDList',
                reader : {
                    type : 'json',
                    totalProperty : 'total'
                },
                extraParams : {
                    param : '{params:{appid:"'+Application.app.globals.appid+'"}}'

                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Try to define appid in Application.js. In Application.js if you have as global myParam then you can do something like this: Application.getApplication().myParam

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked in the browser console that the appid is indeed set in the application, but not on the store proxy, the only possible reason is that the code that sets the appid is executed after the code that defines the store.

Store definition is executed really early, directly after the is file read.

You can try whether it helps to set the value in the constructor of the store instance. Instance constructors are executed later, when the store instance is created based on the definition.

```
Ext.define('Application.store.online.ApplicationDev', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId : 'appliaction',
    constructor: function() {
        this.callParent([{
            autoLoad : false,
            pageSize : 18,
            fields : ['total'],
            proxy : {
                type : 'ajax',
                url : 'GetApplicationIDList',
                reader : {
                    type : 'json',
                    totalProperty : 'total'
                },
                extraParams : {
                    param : '{params:{appid:"'+Application.app.globals.appid+'"}}'

                }
            }
        }]);
    }
});
```

If this is still too early, you can set the extraParams in the beforeload event, which is executed even later (directly before the first call to the server is done).

```
Ext.define('Application.store.online.ApplicationDev', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId : 'appliaction',
    autoLoad : false,
    pageSize : 18,
    fields : ['total'],
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : 'GetApplicationIDList',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            totalProperty : 'total'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        beforeload: function(store) {
            store.getProxy().setExtraParam("param",
                '{params:{appid:"'+Application.app.globals.appid+'"}}'
            );
        }
    }
});
```